# Tensorflow Estimator InvalidArgumentError

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to find a way to find and fix a bug in my TF code. The snippet of code below succeeds at training the model, but generates the following error when last line (model.evaluate(input_fn)) is called:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
/var/folders/kx/y9syv3f91b1c6tzt3fgzc7jm0000gn/T/tmp_r6c94ni/model.ckpt-667.data-00000-of-00001; Invalid argument
     [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at ../text_to_topic/train/nn/nn_tf.py:266)  = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda3/envs/tt/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
```

The exact same code works when used with MNIST data set, but doesn't work when used with my own dataset. How can I debug this or what could be the cause. It seems the graphs don't match after the model is restored from a check point, but I'm not sure how to proceed to fix this. I've tried with TF version 1.11 and 1.13

```
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(get_nn_model_fn(num_classes))

# Define the input function for training
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=X_train, y=y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

# Train the Model
model.train(input_fn, steps=num_steps)

# Evaluate the Model
# Define the input function for evaluating
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=X_test, y=y_test,
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Use the Estimator 'evaluate' method
e = model.evaluate(input_fn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error often happens when you modify some part of the graph, e.g. change size of hidden layers or remove/add some layers, and estimator tries to load the previously checkpoints. You have two options to fix the issue:

1) Change model directory (`model_dir`):

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir='./NEW_PATH/', ) # new path
model_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, config=config)
```

2) Delete previously saved checkpoints in the model directory (`model_dir`).

---

*You are sure graph is untouched?*

Be sure, the new dataset has the same `Data-type` as before. If you load float numbers previously for the inputs, in the new dataset they should be float numbers too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm pretty sure the graph is untouched - the code you see above is all I have (it fails on the last line). The issue doesn't occur for a MNIST dataset, but only for another dataset. It could indeed be related to data-types, though so far I wasn't able to identify exactly where the problem occurs. I will look into this some more.

Comment: @foobar Can you mention the "another dataset"? because I tested with fashion_mnist, it was just fine.

Comment: It's a dataset of tf-idf features generated by sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer  => (<14953x972981 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 10352907 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>). I then convert it to an array (as requried by tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn) like so -data.toarray(), so the data.shape is (14953, 972981). It's quite a large number of features.

Comment: I have found a limit on a number of features - anything below ~16k is fine, anything above generates this error. Of course I had way too many features, but it's still kind of strange that there's a limit and the type of error it triggers.

Comment: @foobar Did you increase the size of queue_capacity in numpy_input_fn? Probably fix your issue.

Comment: I didn't know about that option, thanks! It didn't fix the issue though unfortunately (tried with a few options upto 100k with 17k features). For now I'm just using less features. Thank you for your help!